# Cannot import module torchaudio.prototype

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory, speech-to-text, ctc, torchaudio

I wanted to make ctc_decoder using torchaudio ctc_decoder module. According to this tutorial [ASR INFERENCE WITH CTC DECODER](https://pytorch.org/audio/main/tutorials/asr_inference_with_ctc_decoder_tutorial.html#:%7E:text=from%20torchaudio.prototype.ctc_decoder%20import%20lexicon_decoder)
it should have been easy to import as usual but I am unable to do so in google colab even after installing torchaudio.
It says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchaudio.prototype'` 
How can I import prototype module?

Comment: Try in uninstall using `!pip uninstall -y torchaudio`,  Then, `!pip3 install torchaudio==0.10.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html`

Answer (score 1):

The prototype feature is only available in nightly builds, so one needs to install nightly version, following the https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ .

Note that since the release of 0.12, the CTC decoder is in beta and is available as `from torchaudio.models.decoder import ctc_decoder`.